# Is PGF-Pie part of TeXlive nowadays?

Tags: texlive, pgf-pie

According to [Nikola Talbot](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/html/pgf-pie.shtml), PGF-Pie used to be part of MikTeX, but not of TeXlive. Is this still the case and if not, in which version was PGF-Pie introduced to TeXlive?

Comment: You can always look that stuff up on ctan: https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf-pie?lang=en

Comment: Thanks @daleif, I never spotted the `Contained in` before. So you want to make this an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a package is available on CTAN it is always listed in on the package description page whether this package is available in MikTeX or TeXLive (mostly they are available in both, but there are certain packages that are not provided by TeXLive due to licensing etc).

In this case https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf-pie?lang=en lists that `pgf-pie` is now available for both MikTeX and TeXLive.